# How to make my program a background process

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I wrote a program in C# .NET, that needs to be run in the background. I mean it should have any user interface. Neither a GUI nor a CLI. It is not also a  `windows service`(because it must run only after user has logged in).

It should just run in background. example of such programs  are `AdobeUpdater.exe` , `GoogleUpdater.exe` etc.

Comment: You realize Google Software Updater does indeed run as a Windows Service under the context of the Local System account ? A Windows service set to automatic startup with Local System Credentials is probably what you need.

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to create a Windows Application and set these two properties:

```
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

Comment: Well, I don't think this is a good solution because, this makes first form to be created & shown then these actions will be executed. Which makes GUI to appear atleast for an instant. Which I want to avoid.

Comment: @ThinkCentre: Try setting the Forms visibility property to false at design time. An application with a "hidden" form is your only option if you don't want to write it as a windows service, so work at getting this to work for you.

Comment: @ThinkCentre: If you set this at design time like @Binary suggested, or if you set this in the Form's constructor, you'll never see the form.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a Console application, and then change it's properties in the project settings to a Windows application (rather than console).  Or you can create a Windows Forms application that ddoesn't actually create any forms.

Answer (score 2):

I often use the following solution for this case: create an application context and use that in the WinForm's project instead of a form.

1. Create an applicationcontext class

   ```
   public class MyApplicationContext : ApplicationContext
   {
           public MyApplicationContext()
           {
           }

           void Exit(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
                   Application.Exit();
           }
   }
   ```
2. In Program.cs -> replace original Application.Run() call

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

       Form1 frm = new Form1(); //remove if not needed 
       Application.Run(new MyApplicationContext());
   }
   ```
3. Because you don't show the form anymore, you need to provide other ways to close the application. I.e. use system tray and then call:

   ```
   Application.Exit();
   ```

Note: Using the above (without ever showing the form), you will never get the usual form events like load, closing, closed.

Answer (score 0):

Use Task Scheduler to run it on a schedule (which can be based on when user logs in).  Or add it to the registry to run on startup.

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

Comment: Thankyou. This is more of a tip than an answer to my query. In visual studio my program is either a `Windows Forms/WPF` (GUI) project or `CLI` project. Now, I don't want either. It should silently run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You might reconsider using a Windows service and having it monitor for logon/logoff events using the `System.Management.ManagementEventWatcher` class. This gives an example of a logoff event watcher: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0c1bded8-0cce-4260-bd28-4b4ffce0d27d.